# Using Getters and Setters in the Karel Midpoint exercise (Java)

Tags: java, setter, getter, getter-setter, karel

Ive written this code to use a bit more Java elements than the course intends. But Im having trouble getting it to work for all 4 directions. The getters and setters are embedded into the methods that make Karel move. If i can get any help making this cod work that would be great.

```
import stanford.karel.*;

public class MidpointFindingKarel extends SuperKarel {


public void run(){
    while(facingEast()){
        moveEast();
    }
    while(facingNorth()){
        moveNorth();
    }
    while(facingWest()){
        moveWest(moveEast());
    }       
    while(facingSouth()){
        moveSouth(moveNorth());
    }
}

    private int moveEast(){
        int width = 0;
        while(frontIsClear()){
            width++;
            move();
        }
        turnLeft();
        width /= 2;
        return width;
    }

    private int moveNorth(){
        int height = 0;
        while(frontIsClear()){
            height++;
            move();
        }
        turnLeft();
        height /= 2;
        return height;
    }

    private void moveWest(int _width){
        for(int _w = 0; _w < _width; _w++){
            move();
        }
        turnLeft();
    }

    private void moveSouth(int _height){
        for(int _h = 0; _h < _height; _h++){
            move();
        }
        turnLeft();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please specify, what your code is supposed to do?
If all you want to do is put a beeper in the midpoint at every wall, I would just make a separate method that does that.
If my solution does not answer your question, sorry in advance!

```
import stanford.karel.*;

public class MidpointFindingKarel extends SuperKarel {
public void run(){
    while(facingEast()){
        moveEast();
    }
    while(facingNorth()){
        moveNorth();
    }
    while(facingWest()){
         moveEast(); // I did not understand what "moveWest(moveEast());" was for. 
    }       
    while(facingSouth()){
        moveNorth();// I did not understand what "moveSouth(moveNorth())" was for. 
    }
}

    private void moveEast(){
        int width = 0;
        while(frontIsClear()){
            width++;
            move();
        }
        goBackPutBeeperReturn(width); // goes back half of the "width", puts beeper, returns.
        turnLeft();
       // width /= 2; 
        // return width; 
    }

    private void moveNorth(){
        int height = 0;
        while(frontIsClear()){
            height++;
            move();
        }
        goBackPutBeeperReturn(height);
        turnLeft();
       // height /= 2;
       // return height;
    }


  //Pre-condition: Karel has finished going along a wall and has its length stored somewhere. 
  //Post-condition: Karel has put a beeper in the midpoint and is back to the end of that wall
    private void goBackPutBeeperReturn(int wallLength){
           turnAround();
           for(int loop = 0 ; loop < wallLength/2 ; loop++){
            move();   
           }
           putBeeper();
           turnAround();
           for(int loop = 0 ; loop < wallLength/2 ; loop++){
                move();
       }}}

       /*
   private void moveWest(int _width){
        for(int _w = 0; _w < _width; _w++){
            move();
        }
        turnLeft();
    }

    private void moveSouth(int _height){
        for(int _h = 0; _h < _height; _h++){
            move();
        }
        turnLeft();

    }


}*/
```